# База данных для приложения на React Native

Tags: node.js, база-данных, reactjs, react-native, expo

Хочу создать приложение на React Native с картой интересных мест. Для этого нужна база данных, чтобы вписать туда координаты, название описание и тд и как-то вытаскивать оттуда всю эту информацию. Какую можете посоветовать для этого базу данных? Читал много про Firebase, но не очень понял, можно ли там вручную вписывать новые эклементы. Так же знаю, что для обычного реакт приложения отлично подойдет Strapi, но не слышал, чтобы Strapi можно было подключать к RN или Expo проектам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мы говорим про **Strapi**, то это CMS, в которой через админку можно создавать свои сущности для дальнейших **CRUD** (**C**reate **R**ead **U**pdate **D**elete) операций. Подключать БД к проекту не нужно, т.к. взаимодействовать с этой CMS можно только по API. Это значит, что Вам достаточно развернуть эту CMS у себя локально, создать нужные Вам сущности, а потом взаимодейстовать по API (как это делается, Вы можете посмотреть в документации **Strapi**). Когда же вы захотите выкатить приложение на prod, Вам нужно будет купить хостинг, а затем залить Вашу CMS на него и обращаться уже к ней